# Data Not Displaying in Drop Down by mysqli

Tags: php, html

I have a small data entry form which works well, but someone asked me if I can have the 'name' field as a drop down box of users as opposed to having to type in a name and risk a spelling mistake - yep makes sense.
This is pretty new to me and following some information on here and other sites I have tried to accomplish the first part.. populating the drop down box..  nope.  No errors, just nothing in the box.
To power this I have tblStaffNames (userID, txtName)

The code I am using looks like this;

```
<?php
include("connect-db.php");
$queryNames = "SELECT txtName FROM tblStaffName";
$resultNames = $conn->query($queryNames);
?>

<select name="personname">
<?php
while ($rowNames = $resultNames->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=\"{$rowNames['txtName']}\">";
    echo $rowNames['txtName'];
    echo "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

The $conn is all good as on another page I can display data in a table from the database, including tblStaffNames - so I can rule out any sort of connection issues.

When I run the page, the little drop down box appears, very simple like but it's there, just no values.

I will end up using the value like this as part of the data entry form;

```
<td><select name="personname" style="width:100px" ><?php echo $RowNames;   ?></select></td>
```

But I can't actually get to the point of displaying data.

Can anyone help me out with what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: html select only display the Option values.

Comment: **The rule No.1:** Don't stare at the rendered page, **always check the HTML source** generated by your code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code with slight changes. It works for me. Please check your DB connection is OK as I have done in my code.

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "staff_db";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $queryNames = "SELECT txtName FROM tblStaffName";
    $resultNames = $conn->query($queryNames);


    //Generating the Dropdown
    echo "<select name=\"personname\">";
    while ($rowNames = $resultNames->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<option value=\"{$rowNames['txtName']}\">";
         echo $rowNames['txtName'];
         echo "</option>";
     }


    echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: ok yes that worked now, I think there was an error in the connection now.  Am I correct to understand that the value selected from txtName is stored in $rowNames?  I can write that value to the table is all.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Stevenls $resultNames->fetch_assoc() returns the resulted raw from the DB as an Associative array(array with key value pairs). So, $rowNames is assigned that array and you can call values by key as $rowNames['txtName'] and do whatever you need like printing, comparison etc.  Since, we are looping you can receive all the particular values from the DB.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what your error but for better understanding i change your code like this

```
$queryNames = "SELECT userID,txtName FROM tblStaffName";
$resultNames = $conn->query($queryNames);
?>

<select name="personname">
<?php
while ($rowNames = $resultNames->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $rowNames['userID'];  ?>">
     <?php echo $rowNames['txtName'];  ?>
   </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Following code snippets works for me.

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "password";

    //DB Server Connection
    $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection establishment failed");

    //DB Selection
    $selected = mysql_select_db("staff_db", $conn) or die("Could not select DB");

    //Query String
    $queryNames = "SELECT txtName FROM tblStaffName";

    //Query the DB
    $resultNames = mysql_query($queryNames);

    //Generating the Dropdown
    echo "<select name=\"personname\">";
    while ($rowNames = mysql_fetch_array($resultNames)) {
         echo "<option value=\"{$rowNames['txtName']}\">";
         echo $rowNames['txtName'];
         echo "</option>";
     }


    echo "</select>";

?>
```